# Query about scope of variables in java

Tags: java

```
public class Knowing {

    static final long tooth = 343L;

    static long doIT(long tooth) {
        System.out.print(++tooth + " ");
        return ++tooth;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.print(tooth + " ");
        final long tooth = 340L;

        new Knowing().doIT(tooth);
        System.out.println(tooth);
    }
}
```

Okay so here is my question:

- If we have a global variable declared `static final long tooth = 343L;` How can we have another variable in the main method declared `final long tooth = 340L;` I just want to know why this is allowed because I ran it and there was no error?
- And also shouldn't the access of the global static variable tooth be by using *className.variableName* and not by creating a new *instance.variable* name how come that is allowed with only a warning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can we have another variable in the main method declared final long tooth = 340L;

Because the language specification says you can. From [section 6.4.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1), about *shadowing*:

> A declaration d of a local variable or exception parameter named n shadows, throughout the scope of d, (a) the declarations of any other fields named n that are in scope at the point where d occurs, and (b) the declarations of any other variables named n that are in scope at the point where d occurs but are not declared in the innermost class in which d is declared.

Should you *do* this? Rarely. On the other hand, I've rarely seen it be a problem, either.

For your second question:

> And also shouldn't the access of the global static variable tooth be by using className.variableName and not by creating a new instance.variable name how come that is allowed with only a warning?

This is a design flaw in Java, IMO. Even the warning isn't part of the language specification. You should *always* avoid doing this, as it makes the code do something other than it looks like it's doing. The example I usually give is:

```
Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(someRunnable);
backgroundThread.start();
backgroundThread.sleep(1000);
```

That makes the *executing* thread sleep, not the new thread.

Answer (score 2):

The local variable eclipses the global.  But you can still get to the global by using classname.variable.

Answer (score 1):

The `tooth` variable in `main` is a local variable and takes precedence over global variables. If you wanted to access the global one, you should reference it as follows `this.tooth`.

If you want to read more about variables and scopes I suggest reading the [Oracle Docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

Answer (score 1):

Parameter/variable hiding is a common feature in language design.  There is, for example, no way for the client of a method in a third-party library to control the names that library used for formal parameters.  Another common practice in language design is consistency.  Here that means that anyplace you can declare a variable, you can hide a like-named one from an outer scope.  Note that if you try to declare a local variable of the same name as a variable in the *same* scope, you will get an error from the compiler.

Non-static access of static variables is a convenient feature when using the Builder pattern.  However, it is deceptive (as another answer has graphically demonstrated) so the compiler flags it as a warning.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `className.variableName is a legal way of accessing a static member, but its possible to create an instance of the class which has the static member` , to access that static member. consider this as a bug or flaw, It becomes impossible in classes like Math, where constructor is private, and moreover there are no instance variables in that class, so its useless to create an object.
and for the Scope thing pls look at this link
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1